# MATLAB: Data points not smooth enough, use Excel?

Tags: matlab, netlogo

I'm currently working on my undergraduate thesis regarding Traffic Simulation via Netlogo. My simulation involves the drive cycles of vehicles after some set time. I export the data (in the form of .txt files about the vehicles velocity, time, gear and acceleration) and use MATLAB+Simulink's Quasi-Static Toolbox to analyze Drive Cycle data. However, whenever I feed data into the Quasi-Static Toolbox, it doesn't give out the plots about fuel consumption. My instructors have told me that my data isn't "clean" enough for the QSS Toolbox, and it needs to be "smoothed" in order for MATLAB to give out plots and graphs. I have inserted images below:

Here is my Drive Cycle data:

[image]

Whenever I run it, the plots don't give out anything as seen here:

[image]

Now this is a sample data by one of the previous proponents of the thesis. Notice that his drive cycle is smooth and almost box-like:

[image]

My instructor has told me that MATLAB doesn't give out plots because:

a.) The # of drive cycle inputs are lacking
b.) The data isn't smooth enough

I have 108000 pts worth of data for velocity, time, gear and acceleration, so I think b.) is more of the problem here. If so, how can I smooth my data? Do I use Excel? How?

EDIT: It seems I have been taking the sqrt of a negative number:
[image]

Comment: Can you describe more accurately what you want to happen, preferably with data examples? I am quite sure that your definition of 'smooth' is not a regular one.

Comment: Ah, well, as seen from the picture above. Our datapoints (indicated in the green box) is "rough around the edges." That is why MATLAB shows NO PLOT (as seen again above) regarding fuel consumption and battery voltage etc (I am modelling a Series Hybrid Vehicle). As opposed to the other picture, where the datapoints looks clean, almost box-like. When ran in MATLAB, it gives out plots and graphs because apparently, MATLAB cannot plot rough data points (like ours). What I mean is that, is there anyway to "clean" our data points? (Removing sudden spikes and what not)

Comment: +1 for the interesting question :) when you said, you have insufficient data points, do you mean you want to **interpolate** the edges and any blanks?

Comment: @bonCodigo Well sir, not really, what we want to do is merely make MATLAB make plots of Fuel Consumption using our drive cycle, but since it cannot, we suspect that our data points have too many spikes and erratic behavior (unlike the bottom one) for MATLAB to make a plot of

Comment: I really assume that you have tried out [Matlab smoothing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/smoothing-data.html). The next relatively ugly guess would be to do remove the spikes, and perhaps a **weighted average** or **co-vaiance** to clean up... Do you have a method already implemented to detect the spikes? How do you plan to define a spike? using certain average **threshold**?

Comment: @bonCodigo Sadly, I have not tried Matlab smoothing yet, I am actually new to Matlab and have no idea of smoothing techniques.

Comment: Before you assume it has anything to do with "smoothing" you should make sure the data make sense - for example, perhaps the data you're trying to plot contain `NaN` (not a number) from a divide-by-zero or something like that.  Try plotting the data yourself manually, before using a more involved script.  Google "matlab plot" for documentation if you need it.

Comment: @tmpearce +1 Now that's prehaps the best approach to breakdown the steps and narrow down your issue ;)

Comment: I see! Actually now that you've mentioned it, I just realized something, let me update my post. It seems that I have been taking the sqrt of a negative number.

Answer (score 1):

Please be clear about whether the problem is solved now or what exactly you want to solve.

Assuming your question is: How can i make the data from the upper green box look more like the one in the lower green box

Here is a method:

Smooth the data, suppose your data is in the vector `x` you can smooth it with

```
x_smooth = smooth(x)
```

Make it blockwise, determine where you want the boundries to be, say:

```
lower = min(x);
upper = max(x);
treshold = mean(x);
```

Now force it to the edges

```
idx = x_smooth > treshold
x_smooth(idx) = upper;
x_smooth(~idx) = lower;
```